# Number of homomorphism from $Q_8/\Bbb{Z}(Q_8)$ to $D_4/\Bbb{Z}(D_4).$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

**Problem**- Find the number of homomorphism from $Q_8/{Z}(Q_8)$ to $D_4/{Z}(D_4).$

**Attempt**-  Since $|Q_8/Z(Q_9)|=4$ and group of order $4$ is always abelian in this case $Q_4$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_4$ and any abelian group of order $4$  is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2×\Bbb{Z}_2$. Similarly $D_4/Z(D_4)≈\Bbb{Z}_2×\Bbb{Z}_2$.
Is answer $16$?

Please someone explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, where did the number $16$ come from?

Comment: homomorphism from Z₂×Z₂ to Z₂×Z₂. So i think each has 4 choices.

Comment: Each what? You are on the right track, and I think if you write up precisely what you mean, you can see more precisely why it is correct.

Comment: Each means Z₂×Z₂ have four ordered pair element and so each element has 4 choices.

Comment: If each of the $4$ elements had $4$ possible choices, that would lead to way more than $16$ maps. But you need to note that once you have chosen for two of them, the rest will be given.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it is time for you to spend a bit more time thinking about this, so I will not comment further for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $G:=\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}=\{e,x,y,z\}$ when $e$ is the identity. Every element is the inverse of itself, $xy=z$, $xz=y$, $yz=x$ and the group is abelian.

Now, I say a function $\varphi:G\to G$ is a homomorphism if and only if $\varphi(e)=e$ and $\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=\varphi(z)$. Let's prove it. If $\varphi$ is a homomorphism then it obviously satisfies these two properties. As for the other direction suppose $\varphi$ has the two properties. Every element is the inverse of itself so for any $g\in G$ we have $\varphi(g^2)=\varphi(e)=e$ and also $\varphi(g)\varphi(g)=e$ (because $\varphi(g)\in G$ as well) and hence $\varphi(g^2)=\varphi(g)\varphi(g)$. Also by multiplying the equation $\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=\varphi(z)$ by $\varphi(y)$ on both sides we get $\varphi(yz)=\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)\varphi(z)$ and in a similar way by multiplying $\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=\varphi(z)$ by $\varphi(x)$ we get $\varphi(xz)=\varphi(y)=\varphi(x)\varphi(z)$. And of course for all $g\in G$ we have $\varphi(ge)=\varphi(g)\varphi(e)$. So $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

So that way we get that we are free to choose the images of $x$ and $y$ but that's it. We can't choose the images of $e$ and $z$, they are dependent. We have $4$ options to choose the image of $x$, $4$ options to choose the image of $y$ so we conclude there are $16$ homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$ to itself.

Comment: Well, I guess this saves the OP from having to think about this themselves.

Comment: Is there any method to determine by taking gcd?

Comment: Well thank you. It is interesting.

Comment: If we want to evaluate number of homomorphism from Zₙ×Zₙ to Zₙ×Zₙ. Then how do we get this?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft, I hope OP will understand and learn from this so next time he can do that on his own.

Comment: @user469000 you can take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088471/determining-all-homomorphisms-from-def-z-bbb-z-z-n-times-z-m-to-itself